# which types of Differential equations can be solved using Laplace transformation? which are not possible to solve using Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

please if you are not going to answer and instead tell me that I should know this because its 3rd grade math then simply dont respond. I never get straightforward answers on this forum, only sarcastic ones. I am not a math prodigy I dont understand all notation, I just want an answer to the question, not a reality check that I know nothing.

I believe this question can be easily answered by those who know

Thx to those that will answer in a straightforward manner.

Comment: The only time people may leave "sarcastic" comments is if you post a question without any attempt of your own first. The reason is - is because people are willing to help you, but not willing to just do the work **for you**. It's nothing personal, but you should be adding context to questions to make it more helpful to you and potentially future people asking the same question. For example, your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777991/how-to-solve-second-order-differential-equation-with-3-variables lacks context - you didn't add your own attempt first

Answer (score 1):

In general, the Laplace Transform is usually applied to the Linear Differential Equations, with constant coefficients and non-homogeneous (when $g(x)$ is any function different than a constant, i.e. a function of the denpendent variable, $x$). For instance:

$$y'''(x) - 5y'(x) = g(x)$$

However, we may use the Laplace Transform so as to solve some integro-differential equations (equations with derivatives of $y$ and integrals) as well as some definite and improper integrals. For instance:

$$y''(x) + y'(x) + \int_0^xy(u)du = g(x)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

That's possible because:

$$\mathcal{L} \left( \int_0^xy(u)du \right) = \frac{\bar{y}(s)}{s}$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your straightforward answer. Just one simple question. what is y¯(s). (the function y with the bar on the top)?

Comment: That's the Laplace transform of $y$. We usually denote it as: $\mathcal{L}(y) = \bar{y}$. And you must remember that this transform takes the domain, usually $t$ or $x$, and transforms it into $s$, another domain.

Comment: @ArmanBraca Indeed, Linear DE's are where it's used most frequently. Note that we can actually also use the Laplace Transform to solve Partial Differential Equations!

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose oh yeah, thanks! Forgot those. Laplace Transforms are quite useful when dealing with PDEs too.

Comment: No problem buddy!